# Probability that exactly $r$ tables are occupied if $k$ people randomly select a table

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ tables with infinite capacity.

Each of the $k$ guests randomly (with uniform distribution) and independently select a table to sit next to. What is the probability that exactly $r$ tables will be occupied (have at least one guest sitting next to it)?

In other words, if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k$ are i.i.d. with discrete uniform distribution on $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, what is the probability

$$P(|\{X_1\} \cup \{X_2\} \cup \dots \cup \{X_k\}| = r)?$$

I'm not sure I understand how to approach this problem in a good way and get a nice answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick which $r$ tables are occupied.  Pick a partition of the $k$ people into $r$ non-empty subsets and pick how the groups of people correspond to the tables selected.

We do this using [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Recognize that there are $n^k$ possible equally likely arrangements.

The probability is then:

$$\dfrac{\begin{Bmatrix}k\\r\end{Bmatrix} r! \binom{n}{r}}{n^k}$$